# How to rewrite the following function so it doesn't use for loops?

Tags: javascript

The following function takes an object, loops through each value and returns `false` if the object or its children have an empty or undefined property `web`. Otherwise, it returns `true`:

```
hasNoCategories (object) {
  for (let key in object) {
    const value = object[key]
    for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      const item = value[i]
      if (item.web !== undefined && item.web !== '') return false
    }
    if (key === 'web' && value !== '') {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
},
```

Example input:

```
{
  "livingroom": [],
  "garage": [],
  "outdoors": [],
  "other": [],
  "id": "ZI4hteKxgr",
  "name": "Cuiti",
  "description": "",
  "user": "",
  "date": "2016/5/13",
}
```

How to rewrite this function without using for loops?

Comment: @James111 the output are just `true` or `false`.

Comment: you use `key` before you set it to a value.

Comment: i don't really get the question. If you want to check if something is inside an array, you can't escape the fact that you have to do some iteration using for-loops or a function that does it for you.

Comment: @Nina Scholz You're right. I fixed the code.

Comment: Jeez, first time I post a question with 4 downvotes, and that gets two answers with two downvotes.

Comment: @alex I don't think these downvoters know what they're doing. Do not be discouraged by them.

Comment: you missed **some** examples with the **wanted** results.

Comment: @alex What does "child" mean to you? Is it an object that is in an array that is in `object`? If so then your solution is fine. Also is it a direct descendant or any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you expect the code to do, because your existing code and your description differ.

Your description is, rephrased, that this function checks whether `object.web` or any `object.XXX.web` are undefined. Your code however assumes that all members are arrays and checks whether `object.web` or `object.XXX[YYY].web` are undefined. (Note that it also doesn't do it correctly and accesses `.length` even though the member in question might be undefined.)

Since I'm not sure which of those is right, I'm providing two answers.

**Functionality as per your textual description:**

```
function hasNoCategories(object) {
    if(!object.web) return false;
    return Object.keys(object).every(function(key) {
        if(typeof object[key] !== 'object') return true;
        return !!object[key].web;
    });
}
```

**Functionality as per your existing code:** (but with the `length` property access fixed)

```
function hasNoCategories(object) {
    if(!object.web) return false;
    return Object.keys(object).every(function(key) {
        if(!Array.isArray(object[key])) return true;
        return object[key].every(function(el) {
            if(typeof object[key] !== 'object') return true;
            return !!el.web;
        });
    });
}
```

To understand how this works, check out the documentation on [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) (which returns an array with the names of all keys in your object) and [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) (which runs a callback function for every element in an array and returns true only if the callback returned true for every element).

Note that I'm assuming that your "empty or undefined" should reject all kinds of falsy values including `null` and the number (not string) zero. If not, then all the checks like `if(!something)` and `return !!something` would need to be changed to `if(typeof something === "undefined" || something === '')` and `return typeof something !== "undefined" && something !== ''`, respectively.

Side note to prevent nitpicking: Of course there are still loops going on. But it was specifically asked "without `for` loop" and there is no `for` in this code.

Comment: It's of course `.every` and not `.all`, I already had this fixed yesterday but it appears it was reverted somehow...?

Comment: To be precise: this is without "`for` keyword", not without "`for` loop".

Answer (score -2):

I assume this is what you are looking for:

```
var hasNoCategories = function(object) {
    if (!object.web) {
        return false;
    }
    for (let key in object) {
        var value = object[key];
        if (!value.web) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

I got rid of 1 loop. But this cannot be done without loops because you have to loop over all children. You can hide this loop inside some another function but you cannot get rid of it.

Comment: OP wants to do it without using loops

Comment: Dude, it obviously cannot be done without loops (since you have to iterate over children). But it can be done without 2 loops.

Comment: Please see my answer. By the way -1 is not form me.

Comment: @CharlieH So, you are hiding huuuge looping overhead in `.stringify` and `.indexOf` methods (so you actually use at least 2 loops, potentially more due to recursive jsonification) and you tell me it is without loops? :D And all of that in an incorrect solution? Amusing.

Comment: BTW I would really like downvoters to comment why they downvoted me.

Answer (score -3):

If you really don't want to use loops (I don't know why), one of your options is to serialize the object and phrase the string for the word "web".

```
var s = JSON.stringify(object);

var webIndex = s.indexOf('web');
```

Now perform some checks around this index to ascertain if that has the value `'undefined'` or `''`. Please keep in mind that the word "web" can match as a part of another property name too. So, you need to include this possibility too to your checks.

Comment: I would very much like to know why this method doesn't work :)

Comment: I admit its a good solution. Nevertheless, indexOf do perform some iteration, but I get your answer. (Voted you up because it seems there are no looping ;) )

Comment: It is incorrect solution. What if `object.x == 'web';`?

Comment: @StianStandahl I can wrap my `for` loop into a separate function as well. Does it mean there is no looping? There are lots of loops in this solution. Not only `.indexOf` but also loops in `.stringify` and recursion as well. Huge overhead. Plus the solution is not good - it is incorrect.

Comment: it "seems" there are no for loop. But, there is not way of checking something inside a for loop without some looping.

Comment: @StianStandahl `function my_test(obj) { return hasNoCategories(obj}; }` It seems there are no loops in my solution. It is even one liner. :) Please +1 me.

Comment: OP asked a solution without using `for` loop. And I did it without using `for` loop. The word 'web' can occur in other places than properties. That's why I said that he need to find the index and check around it to ascertain if that is what he is looking for.

Comment: @CharlieH Please show me how to check it when `web` word occures as a **value** not a property name. Or when a child of a child of a child has `web` property. Show me working solution, not "please write your own code". This is pathetic. Your solution is completely broken, beyond repair (due to recursive nature of jsonification). Plus what you think about my `my_test` solution? No loops at all.

Comment: My solution is pathetic and it is completely broken. I guess this saves time.

Comment: @CharlieH Your solution is incorrect which I've obviously shown. And you state that it can be fixed. Then do it. Otherwise delete it. Programmers nowadays...